# How to change position of CartoDB legend in Editor?

Tags: carto, legend

I have a map [here](https://ecbettinger.cartodb.com/viz/3b0cca18-0340-11e6-bc27-0ecfd53eb7d3/public_map) that I'm building in Editor with some custom CSS. 
I'm having trouble positioning my legend in the place I want it on the screen.
I referred to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137277/moving-legend-with-cartodb-js/137281#137281), and tried following the instructions from iriberri, but my solution isn't working.

My goal is to get the legend on the lower left of the screen.

Here's my code:
[image]

and here's the result. The CSS I wrote in Editor is not overwriting correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked CartoDB customer support for help and they responded:

> The issue is that any non-inline styles are sanitized out of that Editor panel, >for security reasons. Have you tried that when building your map with CartoDB.js? >The styles should work that way.

Makes total sense to me -- the only reason I was so confused was because of the earlier SE thread (which I linked to above), in which a CartoDB staffer provided the solution I was trying to implement. 
Apparently that thread is outdated and non-inline styles are no longer possible in the Editor panel.